# How to convert com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity to my Entity Object?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Why I get an casting error when I try to get some database object using com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query

For example:
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Query q = new Query("User");

```
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);

for (Entity entity : pq.asIterable()) {
   User myUser = (User)entity;
}
```

Comment: Do we have a working solution for this? I'm also facing this situation. Any suggestion would be of great help..

Answer (score 3):

You can not do that. Entities returned are of type `Entity` and in java you can not just cast one type to another.

If you want queries to return objects of custom type, you need some kind of mapping framework, for example [`objectify`](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/). It lets you directly use your classes in database operations.

Comment: But I can do this using JPA query?

Comment: Yes. JPA is another mapping framework that maps entities to your classes.